# Flutter TabBarView doesn't show anything in production mode

Tags: flutter, tabbar

I use CustomScrollView and SliverGrid widget inside one tabs of TabBar in debug mode anything works properly, and first selected tab shows grid contents in TabBarView.
When i publish app, the current tab(Tab One) contents doesn't show until change tab and reselect tab one.
[image: This works only in debug mode without any problem]

This is TabBar:

```
late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 6, vsync: this);
    _tabController.animateTo(2);
  }

  static const List<Tab> _tabs = [
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one), child: const Text('Tab One')),
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two), text: 'Tab Two'),
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_3), text: 'Tab Three'),
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_4), text: 'Tab Four'),
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_5), text: 'Tab Five'),
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_6), text: 'Tab Six'),
  ];

  static  List<Widget> _views = [
    AdvFavoritesList(),
    const Center(child: const Text('Content of Tab Two')),
    const Center(child: const Text('Content of Tab Three')),
    const Center(child: const Text('Content of Tab Four')),
    const Center(child: const Text('Content of Tab Five')),
    const Center(child: const Text('Content of Tab Six')),
  ];
```

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 6,
        initialIndex: 1,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                  return Colors.blue;
                } if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
                  return Colors.orange;
                } else if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                  return Colors.pinkAccent;
                }

                return Colors.transparent;
              }),
              indicatorWeight: 10,
              indicatorColor: Colors.red,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
              ),
              isScrollable: true,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              onTap: (int index) {
                print('Tab $index is tapped');
              },
              enableFeedback: true,
              // Uncomment the line below and remove DefaultTabController if you want to use a custom TabController
              // controller: _tabController,
              tabs: _tabs,
            ),
            title: const Text('Woolha.com Flutter Tutorial'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          ),
          body: const TabBarView(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            // Uncomment the line below and remove DefaultTabController if you want to use a custom TabController
            // controller: _tabController,
            children: _views,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This is Widget shows in TabBarView (pictures load from web url address with CatchedNetworkImage) by FavoriteCard Widget :

```
class AdvFavoritesList extends StatelessWidget {
  const AdvFavoritesList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(slivers: [
      SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            childAspectRatio: 1.5,
          ),
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              final Post post = posts[index];
              return FavoriteCard(post, context);
            },
            childCount: posts.length,
          )
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Bug Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1leo3JbZdlZG6sZT0b6Njp98rGnSVZKwL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try flutter clean and rebuild the app. Also try separating the context from materialApp.  Can you include full widget that will reproduce the error

Comment: Everything is OK when using constant text in TabBarView, problem occurs when using SliverGrid or GridView in TabBarView as a widget.
There is no any error but at first run Tab one shows blank page after changing tab Tab one's grid content appear.

Comment: Failed to reproduce the issue, check your `FavoriteCard`

Comment: The problem still persist while using simple Text() instead of FavoriteCard.

Comment: I Think this problem occurs when using TabBar in bottom navigation tab.
this also works properly in new activity without bottom tabs.

Comment: Sorry I've forgot to mention I've removed `DefaultTabController` and then test it

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `DefaultTabController` in this case.

```dart
late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController =
        TabController(length: _tabs.length, vsync: this, initialIndex: 2);
  }

  static const List<Tab> _tabs = [
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one), child: const Text('Tab One')),
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two), text: 'Tab Two'),
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_3), text: 'Tab Three'),
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_4), text: 'Tab Four'),
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_5), text: 'Tab Five'),
    const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_6), text: 'Tab Six'),
  ];

  static List<Widget> _views = [
    AdvFavoritesList(),
    const Center(child: const Text('Content of Tab Two')),
    const Center(child: const Text('Content of Tab Three')),
    const Center(child: const Text('Content of Tab Four')),
    const Center(child: const Text('Content of Tab Five')),
    const Center(child: const Text('Content of Tab Six')),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: _tabs,
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: _views,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Yeasin, Unfortunately it doesn't work. I guess there is a problem using TabBar inside bottomNavigationBar and using IndexedStack activities in body section. It work in new activity loaded after button clicked but when application starts, in favorites section it shows blank page.
video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1leo3JbZdlZG6sZT0b6Njp98rGnSVZKwL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Once you use `_tabController` you dont need to use `DefaultTabController`.  &  I have tested with Text and container on `AdvFavoritesList` works fine on chrome

Comment: In chrome or debug mode it works properly but when I release app by flutter build apk --release  It doesn't work and at first show blank page

Answer (score 0):

Using IndexedStack, instead of TabBarView solved my problem. :)

Comment: Do you have any reference code for this ?